# Google sheets 1 query to group first-of last-of data in range

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image: Data]

Hoping to have 1 query formula to grab specific data per part(SKU) within the data. I want per SKU(column A), the sum of Incoming po(Column B), the 1st date purchase(column C), the last cost(column D), and transpose the first 3 characters of suppliers(column E) per SKU.  I have not been able to build a query that can do this.  Is it possible?  I know it would be extremely easy having the data in a DB.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code, please.

Comment: share your data in a spreadsheet please, it could be easier to understand and answer

Comment: I do not yet have useful code that even partially works.  Here is a share google sheet with the data.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jRDmjUVR26_UvnPecc-7qUYR9DUUHwERM_a9Y-T0NRc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

For SKU(column A), the sum of Incoming po(Column B), the 1st date purchase(column C)

```
=sort(QUERY(A10:C,"SELECT A, SUM(B), MIN(C) where A is not null GROUP BY A label SUM(B) '', MIN(C) ''",0))
```

It is not possible to include Latest Cost(Column D)

```
=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(sort(unique(A10:A)),sort(A10:E,3,0,1,1),4,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY({A10:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),min(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", ), 
 "offset 1", ), 
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT(FILTER(A10:D, A10:A<>""), 1, 1, 3, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,4), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A10:E, E10:E&" -"}, 
 "select max(Col6) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col5"), 
 "offset 1", )),,9^9))), " -$", )})
```

[image]